# How to change current window for openGL drawing (linux & GLX)

Tags: c, linux, opengl, x11, glx

I try to make multi-window app for linux. I tried to make like in code below, but in windows it's show only black screen. What could it be?

```
struct argList{
        Display                 *dpy;
        XID                     *root;
        GLint                   *att;
        XVisualInfo             *vi;
        Colormap                *cmap;
        XSetWindowAttributes    *swa;
        GLXContext              *glc;
        XWindowAttributes       *gwa;
        XEvent                  *xev;
        int                     *cop;
        XID                     **wl;
    };
 void *throwMe(void *args){
    argList *argsl = (argList*)(args);
    while(true){
        glClearColor(1,1,1,0.5);
        XNextEvent(argsl->dpy, argsl->xev);
        for(int i = 0; i < *argsl->cop; i++){
            #ifdef stdinLOG
                printf("Checking (%i) window in list...",i);
            #endif
            if(argsl->wl[i] == nullptr)
                continue;
            else if(argsl->xev->xclient.window==*argsl->wl[i]) {
                argsl->vi->visual, AllocNone);
                *argsl->glc = glXCreateContext(argsl->dpy, argsl->vi, NULL, GL_TRUE);
                XGetWindowAttributes(argsl->dpy, *argsl->wl[i], argsl->gwa);
                glXMakeCurrent(argsl->dpy, *argsl->wl[i], *argsl->glc);
                glViewport(0, 0, argsl->gwa->width, argsl->gwa->height);
                glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
                glOrtho(0,100,0,100,0,0);
                #ifdef stdinLOG
                    printf("Event (%p:%i) called from (%p:%i) window\n",argsl->xev,argsl->xev->type,*argsl->wl[i]);
                    printf("Updatin (%p:%i) window\n", argsl->wl[i], *argsl->wl[i]);
                #endif
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                glXSwapBuffers(argsl->dpy, *argsl->wl[i]);
                if(argsl->xev->type == 22) {

                }       
                else if(argsl->xev->type == KeyPress) {
                    glXMakeCurrent(argsl->dpy, None, NULL);
                    glXDestroyContext(argsl->dpy, *argsl->glc);
                    XDestroyWindow(argsl->dpy, *argsl->wl[i]);
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When wl - windows list. It's a array of XID(X window ID)

Comment: Please expand on your question and describe what the problem is in more detail and what the excpeted result is. What have you tried? What worked what didn't?

Comment: When windows shows, that's display only black screen. I tried all glx content commands after """else if( argsl->xev->xclient.window == *argsl->wl[i]... """

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do here but... you might try moving the call to `glClearColor(1,1,1,0.5)` to immediately *after* the call to `glXMakeCurrent(argsl->dpy, *argsl->wl[i], *argsl->glc)` -- otherwise there's a chance (I think) that the `glClearColor` call will be made without a valid context in place.